# Game Center Leaderboard score only updates when app resumes

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

I've got a Game Center leaderboard in my game that I display using my own GUI using data retrieved from the `GKLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` method.

I report new scores using the `GKScore reportScoresWithCompletionHandler` method. My issue is that when I report a new high score for the local player, when I open up my leaderboard GUI (which forces `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` to be called), the player score isn't updated - it's displaying the old one he just beat.

But if I close(not kill) the game and then reopen it and open up the GUI again, hey-presto, the new score is shown.

This tells me that there must be some form of internal caching going on in GameKit that gets reset when the app resumes. I do know that upon the app resuming, GC calls my authenticationHandler to let me know that it has re-authenticated the player so maybe something in that method wipes whatever internal cache is set?

This is the first game I've worked on where I am displaying Game Center data using a custom UI and not the native GC view controller which I've never had this problem with. Has anyone had similar experience with this and could tell me why `GKLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` gives me old data?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it gave me sleepless night especially seeing no answer related to it on stackoverflow and other forums.
Then, i found somewhere that they were reporting new score whenever the level gets completes. And I changed the button from submit leaderboard to show leaderboard, it resolved the issue. I am using GC view controller. and i was only calling showleaderboard as it was a non-custom leaderboard.